# Dúvida com query mysql trazer resultados mesmo que nao tenha nada

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

tenho a seguinte query dentro de um javascript que gera um grafico:

```
<script>
  $(".sparkline_one").sparkline([<?php
    $sql="select 
    count(id) as total,
    DAY(dia_criacao) AS DAY,
    MONTH(dia_criacao) AS MONTH, 
    YEAR(dia_criacao) AS YEAR 
    from chamados where dia_criacao BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND NOW() AND id_empresa='".$_SESSION['clientelogado']['id_empresa']."' GROUP BY YEAR(dia_criacao), MONTH(dia_criacao), DAY(dia_criacao) order by dia_criacao asc";
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $n=0;
    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
      $chamados[]=$result['total'];
      $dias[]="$n: '$result[DAY]/$result[MONTH]/$result[YEAR]'";
      $n++;
    }
    $chamados=implode(",", $chamados);
    echo $chamados;
    ?>], {
      type: 'bar',
      height: '125',
      barWidth: 13,
      tooltipFormat: 'Dia {{offset:offset}}<br>{{value}} chamado(s)',
      tooltipValueLookups: {
        'offset': {
          <?php
          $dias=implode(",", $dias);
          echo $dias;
          ?>
        }
      },

      colorMap: {
        '7': '#a1a1a1'
      },
      barSpacing: 2,
      barColor: '#26B99A'
    });
  </script>
```

ele funciona bem mas tem um único problema:
se houver um dia que não houve chamados em aberto ele não exibe o dia por não haver resultados no meu db.
Gostaria de saber se é possível pelo mysql retornar os dias em que não ha chamados na ordem da consulta e com valor 0 ?
ou se não houver qual a melhor forma de fazer isso ?  ( vou ter que fazer um loop para consultar todo dia separado ?)

Comment: A consulta retorna os dias que não tem chamado? Se retornar a data mas o numero de chamados for `NULL ou 0`, você poderia estar utilizando a função no mysql `ifnull`. Segue link de exemplo: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/

Comment: nao, so retorna os dias com chamado